# SELECT Count(distinct table_name) how can i show or put in label

Tags: mysql, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012

```
SELECT Count(distinct os_number) FROM order_sub o where  isActive=0;

----------


Call Connects()
        MySqlCmd = New MySqlCommand
        MySqlCmd.Connection = Myconnect
        MySqlCmd.CommandText = "SELECT Count(distinct os_number) FROM order_sub o where  isActive=0"
        MyDA = New MySqlDataAdapter
        myDataTable = New DataTable


----------
```

My problem is I don't know how can I put the outcome of my query. This query shows 15 values i=I want it to be put in my label. Anyone knows how can I do or show me the code I really need it badly.

Comment: can u show with the example output...

Comment: http://prntscr.com/6mqd9h

Comment: i want to put that value in my label in visual studio

Comment: label1 the name of the label

Comment: just see the answer below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT Count(distinct os_number) AS label1 FROM order_sub o where  isActive=0;
```

you need to use [ALIAS](http://www.techonthenet.com/mysql/alias.php)